# In App Purchase subscriptions: how to subscribe to multiple channels with the same price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am trying to add a subscription model to my ios app. In this app, we allow users to subscribe the different channels, and each channel charges the same price saying 4.99$. I create the auto-renewable product 4.99$ in App store IAP. Here is the problem: when a user tries to subscribe the second channel. IAP returns that the product has been purchased. It seems apple only record whether you purchase the product or not and it does not support more than one subscribe to the products with same prices? any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: I haven't used subscription pricing for anything, but because you haven't included any code (that might help) I only have your verbiage to go on. If subscription pricing is anything like other IAP, you need a *separate* product ID for *each* "channel". Do you?

Comment: Each of your channels needs to be a separate product and each of your channels needs to be in a separate product group. There can only be one active subscription per product group